# AWS CLI filtering with JQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I'm still trying to understand how to use JQ to get what I want.  I want to get the size of all snapshots in my account older than a specific date and then add them up so that I can calculate cost.  I am able to do this without the date filtering with this.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --profile my_profile_name | jq "[.Snapshots[].VolumeSize] | add"
```

This returns a numerical value.  Without JQ, I'm also able to get a list of snapshots using "query" but I don't think that will be applied when using JQ but I could be wrong.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --profile my_profile_name --owner-ids self --query "Snapshots[?(StartTime<='2022-09-08')].[SnapshotId]"
```

I tried various arrangements using "select" along with my first example.  However, I haven't been able to get anything returned yet.  I appreciate any pointers.

This is the "select" that doesn't quite work.

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --profile my_profile_name | jq "[.Snapshots[]select(.StartTime < "2022-09-08")] | [.Snapshots[].VolumeSize] | add"
```

Edit 11/15/22

I was able to make progress and I found a site that allows you to test JQ. The example is able to select strings and numbers, but I'm having trouble with the date part. I don't understand how to interrupt the date in the format that AWS provides.  I can do the add part, I removed it to simplify the example.

This the the working "select" for a string.  I can only do greater/less than when I use numbers and remove the quotes from the JSON section.

```
.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime == "2022-11-14T23:28:39+00:00") | .VolumeSize
```

[jq play example](https://jqplay.org/s/b1JtVNpivw7)

Comment: You should be able to use `--query` to do this. It uses JMESPath syntax. Take a look at [`sum()`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#sum) -- you should be able to extract the snapshot sizes and then use `sum()` to create a total value.

Comment: I was able to use the regular query to find dates, but what it returns is JSON with all the additional properties of the object.  I thought that was the limitation of the AWS CLI and the reason why someone would use JQ.  Am I wrong in that understanding?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the jq expression you're looking for is:

```
[.Snapshots[] | select(.StartTime < "2022-09-08") | .VolumeSize] | add
```

Without an illustrative JSON, however, it's difficult to test this out; that's one of the reasons for the [mcve guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, at the time I couldn't follow the guidelines because it would mean I was giving access to my AWS account.  However, I updated my original question and found a playground site for jq.

Also, you nailed it, that is the correct select but it just doesn't do the date part correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without jq is this:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids self \
    --query "sum(Snapshots[?StartTime < '2022-11-12'].VolumeSize)"
```

But note that the comparison is **not** done "by date" but by literally comparing strings like `2016-11-02T01:25:28.000Z` with `2022-11-12`.